# How to use webcam using Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, getusermedia

Is there any way to run `getUserMedia` in Internet Explorer and use a webcam (without using Flash)?

Comment: whhyyyy so many upvotes, his question is barely readable -- e.g. "besides these two items".... what two items? Requirements? has anyone else what?  and he hasn't done any research...

Comment: getUserMedia and Flash ?

Comment: What are you attempting to do?  What have you tried already?

Comment: @SteveG but from this topic I got an answer I wanted from DavidC :)

Answer (score 4):

According to this, no.

http://caniuse.com/#search=getuserMedia

This is the only polyfill I can find, and it uses a flash fallback:

https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js

Answer (score 4):

Another tool (WITH flash fallback - since getuserMedia is on development for IE) that worked way much better for me is WebcamJS by jhuckaby:

https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs

*This should be a comment to Mike Robinson's answer, but I can't comment yet.*