# Webcam streaming

Tags: javascript, webcam

```
function kamera(){
var video = document.querySelector("#videoelement");

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
}

function handleVideo(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}

function videoError(e) {
    // do something
}}
```

This script enables your webcam and stream it on the site. It works fine but stream on Chrome is "zoomed". Any suggestion how to fix this?(IE does not support this)

Comment: In my chrome and ff the size of video is the same 1 to 1 (no -zoom) . My OS is ubuntu.

Comment: So the video isnt zoomed? maybe it was zoomed bcs i was using virtual web cam :)

Answer (score 1):

The getUserMedia/Stream API isn't supported on Internet Explorer yet http://caniuse.com/stream

See here for possible workarounds [How to use webcam using Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031741/how-to-use-webcam-using-internet-explorer)